# What are the survival and hazard function of a Gumbel distribution?

Tags: distributions, survival

What are the survival and hazard function of a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition of the survival function $S(t)=1-F(t)$, the survival function is 
$$S(t) = 1 - \exp(-\exp(-(t-\mu)/\beta),$$
using the parameterization of the Wikipedia article.
The hazard function is given e.g. as $h(t) = \frac{-d\ln(S(t))}{dt}$. One gets
$$
h(t) = \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\exp(-(t-\mu)/\beta)}{\exp(\exp(-(t-\mu)/\beta))-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Just confirm, the 'x' in the second equation is actually 't'. Correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed the 'x' should be 't'. I have corrected my response accordingly.